# How to find a place having its GPS coordinates, my GPS coordinates and a radius?

Tags: java, database, web-services, google-maps, gps

I am developing a simple web service strictly connected to a db: the goal is to find a list of places close to me.

My db contains a list of venues: every venue object consists of a unique id, a name, a longitude and a latitude.

The request that arrives to web service consists of my longitude, my latitude and a radius in km.

I want to obtain the list of places located between me and the radius.

Is there a simple way to do this?

So my questions are: is there a specific object to be used in the db that helps me insert GPS coordinates?

And what type of query should I use? (SELECT * FROM venuesList WHERE ???)

Comment: See this ["article" in the Google Maps documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3#finding-locations-with-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the database you have.  At the limit, you can find a square box which describes items near the radius, but in the rectangular box.

```
SELECT * FROM venuesList WHERE xPos >= clientPosX - radius AND 
                               xPos <= clientPosX + radius AND
                               yPos >= clientPosY - radius AND
                               yPos <= clientPosY + radius;
```

However, a r-tree index would give you the "n-closest members" or "within radius" results.

I think sqlite and postgress support r-trees